# Moving a vent/stack pipe

Tags: kitchens, vent

Currently my kitchen vent/stack pipe joins with another stack and I need to move them to allow a window to be installed.

Can I just redirect them to the right hand corner then up that corner stud, under soffit for reconnect or existing roof vent[![enter image description here][1]][1]?

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQQ91.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQQ91.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsTNh.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Where "just" involves maintaining appropriate slope and position, yes. It appears that you have two vents joining **"more than 6" above the flood rim of the highest fixture on the floor"** and you have to respect that - you cannot make the two vents one (nor run them at less than 45 degrees "upwards") below that level, you have to run them as separate vents and join at or above that level. *i.e.* you cannot run "horizontal" under the counter.

Comment: Thinking like this in the red ?

Comment: Nope. Vents have to run "vertical" (defined as 45 degrees or more upward) to more than 6" above the flood rim of the highest fixture on the floor served, and cannot be combined before that level is reached. The current situation that you want to change appears to meet that. Assuming a typical 36" high kitchen sink as the highest fixture, they have to get to 42" before you can run "horizontal" (2% slope, actually) or be combined.

Comment: Ah got it, thanks for your help appreciate it